# How to loop inside cursor in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, cursor, plpgsql

I have a function

```
drop function ProcessReward();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ProcessReward()
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE 
sessionid NO SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT pg."Setting",pg."UserId",pg."Id" FROM "Development"."PersonGame" pg inner join "Development"."Game" g on g."Id" = pg."GameId" pg."GameId"=1 for read only;
titles TEXT DEFAULT '';
rec record;
jsonrec record;
jsonrecord record;
 BEGIN
 OPEN sessionid;
loop

FETCH sessionid INTO rec;
   if not found then
        exit ;
   end if;
       EXECUTE 'select * from "Development"."GameRecipient" where "PersonGameId"=$1' into jsonrecord using rec."Id";
--I want to loop here every row returned by above query
--loop start
        --    do your task

--loop end

end loop;
return titles;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My query

> EXECUTE 'select * from "Development"."GameRecipient" where
>   "PersonGameId"=$1' into jsonrecord using rec."Id";

returns

```
col1   col2     col3
123     324      444
345     222      765
```

I want to process all rows returned by above query,How to achieve this in PostgreSQL.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Comment: thanks man it worked